# How do I find another vector that belongs to a set of vectors which are a basis of $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: probability

### $$u = (3, -1, 5), v = (1, 2, 4)$$

Question: Give another vector, other than u and v, that belongs to the set of vectors for which u and v are a basis.

So I am aware that for a set of vectors to form a basis of a vector space, the vectors should be linearly independent and the set should span the vector space.
In order for the vectors to be linearly independent, they should only have the trivial solution. So the following below should be true.

### $3C_1 + 1C_2 + XC_3 = 0$

### $1C_1 + 2C_2 + YC_3 = 0$

### $5C_1 + 4C_2 + ZC_3 = 0$

However, I do not understand what values I can get for another vector from these equations. I was thinking it’s something along the lines with working out the determinant or using Gauss Jordon, but then again I am not sure what I can do with that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: From what I gather u and v are THE basis for the space, so all that's needed is a linear combination of u and v to produce a vector different from u or v. However it matters if they are THE basis or PART of a basis, this will decide which answer is correct as they answer both those issues separately

Comment: @Triatticus so if i need another vector that forms a basis of the two vectors, I just take a linear combination of both. However, if it was a basis of the vector space then I take the cross product. But, why doesn't it matter, if it is linearly independent or dependent?

Comment: If u and v are the sole basis of the space then your answer will be a vector that is dependent. If u and v are part of a basis then you may need a third vector that is either linear dependent or independent as they only say the answer has to be different from u and v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take the cross-product $u\times v$.

Comment: This is wrong. $u \times v$ is **not** in the span of $u,v$ and OP is asking for a vector for which $u$ and $v$ are a basis.

Comment: I thought he/she wanted to complete $\{u,v\} $ into a basis of $\mathbf R^3$. The title and the body of the question do not ask for the same thing…

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I need another vector such that {u,v,w} is a basis of R3, where w is a new vector.

Comment: Well, I think this id the simplest way to get one. Furthermore it is orthogonal to the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $v$ is not in the span of $u$.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be nonzero, complex constants. Then the vector $w$
$$
 w = \alpha u + \beta v \in
 \text{span} \left\{ 
u, v
\right\}
$$